# IFS returning "FALSE" when using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I used the macro recorder to write the code and when i do it in excel it works fine but when i run the macro is returns "FALSE" in the first cell.  Please note this is within a table.

```
Range("H2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFS([@[x]]>10,""y"",[@[xx]]>10, ""yy"",[@[xxx]]>10,""yyy"",[@]z]="""","""")"
```

Comment: You are testing whether the active cells formula is equal to the string.  If it is not then it will return `FALSE`.  I believe you have one too many `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _`

Comment: Thank you so much, i removed it and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

To **solve** the issue and increase **readability**, you can rewrite your code like this:

```
Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFS([@[x]]>10,""y"",[@[xx]]>10, ""yy"",[@[xxx]]>10,""yyy"",[@]z]="""","""")"
```